# How to display all custom fields associated with a post type - IN THE ADMIN AREA?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, customization, custom-field

I know know how to get all the custom fields from a custom post type, that's easy.

However, when I create a custom post type, it displays a beautiful page automatically in the administration part of Wordpress, but with only "title" and "date" as fields:

[image: no custom fields]

If I want to add a field called "size" for the chimpmonks so that it displays in that administration screen, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an action called [`manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column). This will allow you to add columns to your custom posts page. To be more precise, you need a filter to generate the column and an action to fill it with content. In your case something like this (untested):

```
add_filter( 'manage_chimpmunks_posts_columns', 'set_custom_size_column' );
add_action( 'manage_chimpmunks_posts_custom_column' , 'fill_custom_size_column', 10, 2 );

function set_custom_size_column($columns) {
    $columns['size'] = __( 'Size', 'your_text_domain' );
    return $columns;
}

function fill_custom_size_column( $post_id ) {
    $terms = get_the_term_list( $post_id , 'size' , '' , ',' , '' );
    if ( is_string( $terms ) )
         echo $terms;
    else
         echo __( 'No size', 'your_text_domain' );
    }
}
```